# How to check for user input in bat file when the input that should be checked is a sentence

Tags: batch-file

This is probably a silly question, but I have the following code:

```
if %input%==1 goto n
```

This works. But when I try do check for a sentence, it doesn't. How do I make it work so that it checks for a sentence? I've tried double quotes etc (even though this method works, but then I have to type the double quotes too, for example `if %input%=="test sentence" goto n`. I want it so that I only should type the text test sentence.

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really, really close with your quotes. However, batch compares both sides of the if equality statement *in their entirety*, so you were effectively saying `if test sentence="test sentence"`, which will always return false. Put quotes on both sides of your if statement for it to work.

```
if "%input%"=="test sentence" goto n
```

Comment: Ah, figures! Thanks for the info, it seems very logical, it's always those details.

Comment: correct solution, but wrong explanation. `if test sentence=="test sentence"` will give a syntax error. `if` has two arguments, splitted by a comparison. First argument is `test`, comparison would be `sentence=="test sentence"`, second argument would be `goto` and `n` woud be the command. As the comparison can not be evaluated, there is a syntax error (`... was unexpected at this time`).

Comment: I suppose "never be true" would have been more accurate, although admittedly a bit misleading...